# Access SQL Database Data From C# Plugin To Use In CRM 2013

Tags: sql, plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I was wondering if it was possible to access data from a SQL Database inside a c# plugin in Visual Studio that will be used in CRM Dynamics 2013

If it is possible has anyone got any examples / tutorials of how to do it as this is all completely new to me.

Comment: As mentioned this is all new to me, and so far I've noticed that there are limitations between plugins and CRM 2013. I have tried looking online for help but none has helped as of yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can do it no problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/07/08/accessing-a-sql-database-from-a-microsoft-dynamics-crm-plug-in.aspx

The external DB functions are built into C#, and it looks like the only real limitations are if you are using the hosted version of dynamics, you cannot run fully trusted plugins. This should have no effect on whether or not you can access an external DB. You also wont be able to build "SSRS" reports using TSQL, if thats what you were looking to do. I'm not sure what SSRS reports are, but your question doesnt mention them so I assume its not what you want to do.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9675.microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-limitations-of-dynamics-crm-online-vs-on-premises.aspx

Comment: Hi @UnicornoMarley - This is one article that I had come across, however I couldn't define the  `using Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy;` for some unknown reason and therefore concluded that is may be to do with the article being old and is now been made redundant (which is something I've come across during this project)
My overall goal is simply to select a certain data in a record and display it in a CRM field if there is data there (data field in SQL is optional)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959928.aspx

If you are getting an error on a "using" statement, it generally means you dont have the right packages installed. I'm not sure where you get that package specifically, but it looks like there are 2 different ones you can use. Try looking in Nuget if you are using visual studio 2013.

Comment: That is for Dynamics CRM 4.0 where I am using Dynamics CRM 2013

Comment: Theyre pretty much the same thing as far as what works and what doesnt. The bigger difference is on premise vs on demand. I dont know which one you are using, but the answer to your original question is the same. Can you access an external SQL DB from a plugin? Yes. How? Us the DB connection functions built into in c#. If you have questions about the CRM On Demand specific functions available in C#, thats a different question that I cant answer.